# Segmentation Fault C++ casting issue

Tags: c++, parsing, segmentation-fault

I am writting a parser, and when casting I am having trouble distingushing between a normal class type, and an array class type.

Having something similar to the following would help me a lot:

```
if (expression causes segmentation fault)
  do sth
else
  do sth else
```

If not this, then, what would be a good way to distinguish two classes from each other?

```
if (base->type->GetType() != "") {
char *key = strcpy(key, base->type->GetType().c_str());
     Node *node = (stack->front).Lookup(key);

    if (node != NULL) {
      theclass = dynamic_cast<ClassDeclaration *>(node);
    }

   if (!base->GetType()->IsEquivalentTo(GetType()))
      errReport.FieldNotFoundInBase(field, type);*/
   if (theclass->id->name){ // segfault happens here.
```

- The variable theclass, is sometimes initialized as an actual class, sometimes as an array. the seg faults happens in the line `if (theclass->id->name) {` when there is an array class instead of an actual class, since the array class doesn't really have a name field. I don't really have a way of telling in which type theclass variable is being initialized.

Comment: No. There's no try...catch for segfaults in C++, since segfaults lead to undefined behavior. There's also not really an array "class" type, unless you mean `std::vector`. Arrays in C++ are just pointers to the first element.

Comment: @AlexReinking, Arrays **decay** to a pointer to the first element. Also, there's `std::array`.

Comment: @AlexReinking, The if has nothing to do with it. You could, for example, do `if (sizeof(arr) == 40)`.

Comment: @AlexReinking so I can't use this: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/

Comment: Not for something that would cause a segfault, since it won't actually throw an exception. The program will crash and immediately exit.

Comment: Can you post a relevant code segment?

Comment: @AlexReinking there it is.

Comment: So `dynamic_cast` will fail whenever `node` is not a subclass (or equivalent to) `ClassDeclaration`. Thus, you should wrap the code that references `theclass` in an `if(theclass) { ... }`. You can handle the case when `dynamic_cast` fails in an `else` later.

Comment: Or just wrap it in a try...catch and look for `std::bad_cast`.

Comment: The problem is that the cast is still complete, since technically an array class is still a class. @AlexReinking

Comment: What do you mean by "array class"?

Comment: It's trying to parse an array type. Which is not something I created, but that was built in the language.

Comment: We're definitely conflating some terminology, here... are you using some sort of parser generator like BISON or ANTLR? Is the `array` type an `std::array`, a C++ array (which is not actually a class), or something else?

Comment: There's no such thing as array class in C++. Can you show how you create the object which later ends up assigned to `theclass`?

Answer (score 3):

If `node` is an instance of `ClassDeclaration`, then `dynamic_cast<ClassDeclaration *>(node)` will return `node` "converted" to a `ClassDeclaration*` [1]. Otherwise, *it returns 0* (or, more accurately, `nullptr` cast to `ClassDeclaration*`.

You don't check for the `nullptr` value. Dereferencing a `nullptr` will almost certainly segfault (although technically it's UB, so it could do anything.)

Now, it's possible that something more esoteric is going on and the segfault isn't happening because the `dynamic_cast` failed and returned `nullptr` and you then proceeded to dereference that value. It's possible. We'd all know for certain if you *checked the return value*.

---

Note 1: It's possible for `dynamic_cast` to change the pointer value, for example if the cast-to type is not the first base type of a multiply-inherited object. So I probably shouldn't have put scare-quotes around the word "converted".

Comment: What could possibly be `UB` which causes `SEGFAULT`

Comment: @Manav: dereferencing a non-dereferenceable pointer, such as the result of dynamic_casting something which is not dynamic_castable to the indicated pointer type. (In other words, if `a` is NULL and you try to do `a->something`, it will probably segfault. But technically it's UB, so it didn't have to segfault.)

Comment: @rici 2things: 1. how would i check for nullptr? I would have to assign something as a nullptr in order to use it, right?  2. What do you mean to check for the return value? which one?

Comment: @rici What would be the case when `*` and `&` are overloaded.

Comment: @dizlla: the return value of the dynamic class, which you  do assign to something: theclass. Right after `theclass = dynamic_cast…`, I would expect to see something like `if (!theclass)…`. Not just in this case, anytime `dynamic_cast` is used.